# JavaScript onclick event not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, opencart

We are running Opencart 1.5.6.4 which uses the below code to add an item to cart.

```
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />
```

We've noticed that, on mobile devices, the Javascript onclick event does not appear to be working.

The javascript function is as follows

```
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

                if (json['redirect']) {
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }

                if (json['success']) {
                    $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                    $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
                }   
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: In wich mobile browser the onclick does not work?

Comment: Chrome / Safari - from both iPhone and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ajax was failing due to the www. missing from the website URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding touch events to your code.

```
$("input.button").on("click touchend", function () {
    addToCart($(this).attr("data-product-id"));
});

function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 'slow');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**html:**

```
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" data-product-id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" class="button" />
```

You can find more reference on touch events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, unfortunately your answer broke the button completely.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this function does even run. Place some console.log maybe.

About @volodymyr-duday anwser: instead of return false, there is a method in event object [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

If function doesn't run, try maybe attaching it to touch event like [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend).

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you use jQuery. 
If your click event does not fire, you can try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[your-selector-here]").on("click touchstart", function(){
        //do stuff
    });
});
```

Otherwise, i see you require 2 arguments on your method but on your event you only have one

```
function addToCart(product_id, quantity){}

onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"
```

Comment: Maybe this specific cart item doesn't need to, he uses default value in the first line of function.

Answer (score -2):

Try use **return false** after **AJAX**  to stop bubbling.